# What can `NSWindows95OperatingSystem` be used for in iOS?

Tags: ios, windows

From https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSProcessInfo_Class/Reference/Reference.html

`NSWindows95OperatingSystem`

Indicates the Windows 95 operating system.
Available in iOS 2.0 and later.

Declared in `NSProcessInfo.h`.

What is this for?

Comment: what are you trying to do with it?

Comment: whatever i can .... just don't know what it is. seriously, we just found it by code completion (actually a colleague did) and asked ourselves about the meaning.

Comment: It is just part of cocoa, on which the iOS SDK is build. Probably Apple also has a Cocoa version for the windows platform or may be is form the earlier day of NextStep.

Answer (score 3):

This is likely a relict from earlier days, when NeXTSTEP was ported to other platforms. For example, "OPENSTEP" was developed by NeXT together with Sun Microsystems which ran on Solaris and WindowsNT.

See also wiki: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenStep

Early documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/802-2112/802-2112.pdf